# Whats there besides Explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#

Consider the Example:

```
 public class People : IEnumerable
 {
    private Person[] _people;
    public People(Person[] pArray)
    {
        _people = new Person[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _people[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }
// Explicit Interface implementation
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
    }
// What is this? Its neither overloading nor over riding.. What else is it?
    public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PeopleEnum(_people);
    }
 }
```

I have been through this kind of examples.. but can't make out what it actually is? Plz help

Comment: Please do more research prior to asking your question. This is very basic C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just defining a method on the class. Not every class method has to be an implementation of an interface method.

Comment: Oh... i see. so its just an ordinary method

Comment: Yup. As ordinary as it gets, just about.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another class method.

That being said, this is not a very common thing to do when implementing `IEnumerable`.  A better approach, in the current frameworks, would be to implement `IEnumerable<Person>` directly, and return an `IEnumerable<Person>`.

This would provide a cleaner API, as the usage would be as expected, and it would work with the current framework methods (ie: all of LINQ without using `.Cast<T>`).